# Directly list the available networks in android phone programmatically

Tags: android

I need to directly display the list of available networks in android phone instead of following the options Wireless&networks->Mobilenetworks->Network operators->Select manually etc, is it possible to directly display the list of available networks without following the above steps i tried the following codes..

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS), 0);
```

The second thing i tried is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The third one which i tried is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

When i tried the third one i got the select manually and choose automatically screen but it is blinking and goes off.
What are all the other options which i can use to select the network without any options?